# Kafka consumer - producer performance measurements

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I measure the rate of Kafka producers and consumers in a Java application? Does Kafka broker provides any performance metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka itself exposes lots of performance metrics. At my employer, we use Prometheus to ingest + store those metrics, and a Grafana frontend for graphs + dashboards. We also instrument our apps, including our Java apps with the Prometheus library, and expose+scrape custom metrics to help us understand all aspects of our data pipelines and performance.

Comment: Would you please tell me how can I use Kafka performance metrics? How should I check them?

Comment: When you run your Kafka brokers, set the environment variable `KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/usr/share/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=7071:/usr/share/kafka-0-8-2.yml` with local paths pointing to the files from `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.3.1/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar` and `https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/kafka-0-8-2.yml`

Comment: after that you should be able to see the metrics via doing an http test with `curl my-kafka-broker:7071/localhost`. When you've confirmed that's working, setup a Prometheus server and configure your Kafka brokers as scrape targets. Then you should see your Kafka metrics.

Comment: Thanks I will try and then let you know.

Comment: Is the order of those commands important? I cannot connect to the server on port 7071.

Comment: 7071 is not in the list of listening port

Comment: Kafka doesn't normally listen on 7071. The `-javaagent` plugin I just specified listens on that if it was run correctly. If nothing is listening on 7071, then it isn't running correctly.

Comment: Here is the official blogpost on setting this up: https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-kafka-with-prometheus

Comment: What do you mean correctly? I ran zookeepr first and then Kafka. Do I need to set any configuration parameters? How can I check that is running correctly?